# meteor autorun responds slower than helper

Tags: meteor

i've been battling for a few days with an autorun function that renders elements on a canvas for two players in a board game. the whole process from when 1 player places a move until its visible for the other player took too long. i managed to cut alot by optimizing the code i have written as a meteor beginner, and also by placing the method that updates the game move inside a (meteor.isServer) so it won't first run the method in the move maker's client (it was already just inside the server's folder).
one delay in time which is beyond my understanding, happens from the moment the server finishes with the move making method until the client's autorun begin to run(about 60 ms delay for chrome, and 150(!) for firefox). i've ran some tests to try and narrow down the options for why it happens, the last one was to subscribe to the games collection from a different page, and see if the response time is slow there too. this is the code:

```
Template.Watch.onCreated(function(){
  this.subscribe('activeGames');
  this.autorun(()=>{
    if(this.subscriptionsReady()){
        console.log(Games.findOne().turn + " " + (new Date).getTime());
    }
  });
});


Template.Watch.helpers({

  games: ()=> {
    console.log(Games.findOne().turn + " " + (new Date).getTime());
    return Games.find({result: false});
  }

});
```

now, on the client both console.logs appeared whenever a move was played, the weird thing is that the helper's console.log was fired with no delay, 50 ms before the autorun's console.log which had the same delay as in the game page.
by my poor understanding, if the client knows a change was made to the database, the autorun should simply run, just like the helper simply runs.
i would be very grateful to whoever explains to me the behavior of the autorun that causes that delay, and if there is a way to cancel it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method on the client using Meteor.call, two things happen in parallel:

> 1. The client sends a request to the server to run the method in a secure
>    environment, just like an AJAX request would work A simulation of the
> 2. Method runs directly on the client to attempt to predict the outcome
>    of the server call using the available information.

So here is the reason why your Helper console print before the autorun.

- Your mini-mongo(client side DB) get updated before the server data update according to point number 2.
- According to point number 1, the client sends a request to the server, then server updates the server database. Server re-publish the data to the client and autorun reinitialize in your case.

So the point is your mini mongo(client side DB) updated before the subscription ready. that's why you got console log in helper before your autorun.

One more thing happen when your server data to client::

> If the result from the server comes back and is consistent with the
> simulation on the client, everything remains as is. If the result on
> the server is different from the result of the simulation on the
> client, the UI is patched to reflect the actual state of the server.

Comment: this would only explain why whoever made the turn normally sees the outcome of the move before the second player who did not call the method. i canceled that behavior by placing the method inside (meteor.isServer). the gap i am talking about happens also to the second player who did not call the method, hence his client can only be updated once the server sent the data to him. his helper gets updated immediately once the server sends the data, his autorun updates only 45 ms later (consistently)

Comment: You added if condition "this.subscriptionsReady()" in autorun, So your console log will only appear when the subscription is ready. But in case of your helper, It will show for both ready or in progress status of the subscription. this.subscriptionsReady() is also wait for a ready status from the server, which set this.subscriptionsReady() to true.
make sence ?

Comment: i see... the delay for my test template's autorun did disappear once i removed the subscriptions ready. unfortunately, for my original autorun that renders the canvas board, there was no subscriptionsready to begin with, and still has a delay...

Comment: now having taken another look, it seems the delay still exists, it just got reduced by some. helper is still faster than the autorun by a bit. but it seems the helper itself also has a delay of around 40 ms from the moment the server finished running the method

Comment: When data changes in autorun its run a function named 'requireFlush'. Which using setTimeout callback. Due to that we got a dealy. Please check the link :  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/tracker/tracker.js#L537

Comment: i see. that explains 10 more ms, still lots of lost time left unexplained though. is it possible that the reactive system meteor is using is very easy to use but in the cost of speed? i wonder mostly because while for a turn-based board game, waiting 50 more ms for something isn't a big deal, but it makes stuff like real-time games impossible to make with meteor. is there a way to bypass the system and call client side code for multiple players immediately after the server method finished running? if not through an autorun, then mabye in a non-reactive way? anyway. thanks for your answers!